# unable to use Qt.OpenHandCursor attribute to set cursor shape

Tags: pyqt4, qcursor

I have a python project that do the following import

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
```

I would like to change the cursor's shape at certain point, for example, I would create a new QCursor object

```
self.cursor_oh = QCursor()
self.cursor_oh.setShape()
```

most documentation and searches I did indicate to just set the shape using enum type such as:

```
Qt.OpenHandCursor
```

But, such enum is not recognized and it always results in the following error message:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OpenHandCursor'

So, what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using trying to use `QtCore.Qt.OpenHandCursor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the Qt namespace is under QtCore, so by adding the QtCore qualifier, it found all of the Qt cursor types.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this in PyQt4 but in PyQt6 it has to be:

```
QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.OpenHandCursor
```